# Kubernetes Master incorrectly reports "kubelet does not have ClusterDNS IP configured"

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

I have installed a kubernetes cluster manually according to this guide: https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/centos/centos_manual_config/

I have installed the kubedns and kubernetes-dashboard addons, but when trying to spin up a heapster deployment, the dashboard warns me that "kubelet does not have ClusterDNS IP configured". However, I believe this to be incorrect.
In the kubelet config of my node I have specified:

```
KUBELET_ARGS="--cluster-domain=cluster.local --cluster-dns=10.250.100.53"
```

The IP being the flannel IP of my kubeDNS service.

I believe this is working, since when I let a pod do an nslookup without specifying the server, it works.

```
[root@myKubeMaster]# kubectl exec busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Server:    10.250.100.53
Address 1: 10.250.100.53 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 1: 10.250.100.1 kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Where does this error come from?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there could be an error in how the arguments get passed to the kubelet, could you try splitting out the arguments?(https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/27722#issuecomment-227893612)